# How can DApps interact with solidity smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

What framework is used to send tokens between accounts by accessing solidity smart contract functions?

Say I made a Solidity smart contract called foocoin with the default transfer function. Assuming the function works correctly:

`function transfer(address recipient, uint amount);`

What sort of framework/API is capable of calling this function externally within a game for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your contract only exposes common payment methods like `transfer`, it may be enough for users to interact using a standard wallet.

Beyond that, the most commonly-used tool is the [web3.js library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/), which helps you build client-side JavaScript applications that talk to the smart contracts on the blockchain. A framework like [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) will often make developing these applications more efficient.

These often work in tandem with [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/), a browser extension that manages users' private keys for them and can show a dialog prompting the user to allow them to sign transactions when sent requests by `web3.js`.